# Looking for java equivalent for sending xml string via window.XMLHttpRequest

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

In JavaScript, we have the following implementation:

```
function sendRMSRequest(xmlString, url){

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlRequest.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {processRequest();};
    xmlRequest.send(xmlString);
}
```

xmlString has the following String:

```
<TestRequest xmlns='http://???.???.????' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'></TestRequest>
```

I want to move this functionality to the server side and I can't figure out how to implement this functionality in java.

I currently have the following java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String endPoint = "http://????.????/service";


    String xml =  "<TestRequest xmlns='http://???.???.????' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'></TestRequest>";

    System.out.println(xml);

    URL url = new URL(endPoint);
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoInput(true);
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

    httpCon.setReadTimeout(0);
    httpCon.setConnectTimeout(0);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain"); 
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("", xml);


    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());  

    pw.write(xml);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();  

    System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
    System.out.println(httpCon.getContentType());



    String returnString = null;
    StringBuffer sb = null;
    BufferedInputStream in;

    // set up httpConn code not included same as previous
    in = new BufferedInputStream(httpCon.getInputStream());  

    int x = 0;

    sb = new StringBuffer();

    while ((x = in.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) x);
    }

    in.close();
    in = null;

    if (httpCon != null) {
        httpCon.disconnect();
    }

    returnString = sb.toString();   
    System.out.println("Return String = " + returnString);

}
```

I get the following error when running the code above:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: can you post all the error string?

Comment: Since I'm working on a client application, I don't want to expose any information of the application. I can tell you that I'm sending the same xml string in both examples. (JavaScript and Java). I'm not too concerned with the exception at this point. I would like to know how I can Post an XML string from a Java application. Thanks

Comment: Where does the SAXParseException occur? The code you provided does not use SAX API at all?

Comment: It happens on the server side, which I don't have access to the source at this point.